# CDEvent underlying FSEvent flags always `isGenericChange`

Tags: objective-c, fsevents

I'm using this (older) framework: https://github.com/rastersize/CDEvents to track changes on the filesystem.

For some reason the flag is always `event.isGenericChange`. On the `FSEvent` level this would be the `kFSEventStreamEventFlagNone` (code `0`).

Maybe this has something to do with the framework being older and missing something that changed? I'm not getting any build/test warnings/errors (installed through CocoaPods).

I'm using this code through a delegate:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.events = [[CDEvents alloc] initWithURLs:@[[NSURL URLWithString:@"/Users/username/Desktop/"]]
                                        delegate:self
                                       onRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]
                            sinceEventIdentifier:kCDEventsSinceEventNow
                            notificationLantency:((NSTimeInterval)0.25)
                         ignoreEventsFromSubDirs:NO
                                     excludeURLs:@[]
                             streamCreationFlags:kCDEventsDefaultEventStreamFlags];
}

- (void)URLWatcher:(CDEvents *)URLWatcher eventOccurred:(CDEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"Event: %ld", (unsigned long)event.flags);
}
```

I tried all actions (rename, edit, remove, create, change meta-data, change rights, etc.) and it's always `genericChange`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by adding the `kFSEventStreamCreateFlagFileEvents` flag. Because I'm using CocoaPods I'd rather not adjust the source code so instead of placing `streamCreationFlags:kCDEventsDefaultEventStreamFlags` using these manual flags:

```
(kFSEventStreamCreateFlagUseCFTypes |
 kFSEventStreamCreateFlagWatchRoot |
 kFSEventStreamCreateFlagFileEvents)
```

Guess it has to do with some radical changes Apple did sometime in the past. I'm now getting the correct flags and also the full path to a file (not only it's directory).